# check if request is coming from kubernetes port-forward

Tags: kubernetes

So I have a jwt secured route in my web app, something like this pseudocode

```
checkAuth(token) {
  GET  /route handler()
}
```

This is deployed in a kubernetes cluster, on which we ussually `port-forward`

I'd like to skip the auth check if we port-forwarded, to avoid getting a token everytime

Obviously checking for `localhost` here would not work, what is the best way to go about this?

Comment: The source IP of a port forwarded request will be one of the kubernetes master pod ip's (usually anyone who can schedule workloads on the masters has the keys to the kingdom anyway). Only other difference i can think of is the absence of headers the ingress controller adds, but relying on that sounds like a security issue waiting to happen.

Comment: Maybe source IP + a magic header/token you add in the dev client.